# How to use a PowerShell Script in the Windows "SendTo" folder?

Tags: command-line, shell, powershell, script, send-to

There are instructions on how to use a bash script in the SendTo folder (using the instructions in the below link).  However, I would like to execute a PowerShell script instead.

[Is it possible to use a shell script in the sendto folder](https://superuser.com/questions/608978/is-it-possible-to-use-a-shell-script-in-the-sendto-folder)

I would like for the shortcut to execute a PowerShell function that I have defined in my PowerShell profile called, **Invoke-SendToUPLOAD**... *where Invoke-SendToUPLOAD accepts the full file path of the sendto file as a parameter* by default.

I "almost" have what I want.  However, filepaths that have spaces in them are truncated.  Could someone tell me how to preserve the filepath even if there's a space in the path.  I've tried putting double-quotes around **%1** below.  However, that doesn't work either.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /min cmd.exe /c PowerShell.exe -Command "& {param ($I = {%1} ); Invoke-SendToUPLOAD }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a solution on StackOverflow for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934981/651934

In short, surround the parameter with single quotes. In your case, the following should work:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /min cmd.exe /c PowerShell.exe -Command "& {param ($I = {'%1'} ); Invoke-SendToUPLOAD }"`

The downside is that this doesn't support filenames that contain a single quote. But spaces and other characters work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a way to use a Powershell PS1 script to change the case of selected filenames using the SendTo folder.

Using a batch file with the command lines described in previous comments did NOT work for me.

First, I created the following PS1 script:

```
#filenames-to-lowercase-recursively,ps1
```

Get-ChildItem -recurse |
Where {-Not $*.PSIsContainer} |
Rename-Item -NewName {
$*.FullName.ToLowerInvariant()
}

Then, I converted the PS1 file to an EXE file and copied the EXE file to the SendTo folder.  I used the online converter at [Online Powershell to Exe Converter](https://ps2exe.azurewebsites.net/).

The EXE version of the PS1 file worked perfectly for selecting desired files and running the EXE from the Send to menu.  I could even select multiple files without problems.

Comment: ATTENTION: On the exe I downloaded from the mentioned webpage I am getting a defender warning about malicious components: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=PUA%3AWin32%2FPuwaders.C!ml&threatid=242878